# Before the birth of computers how people calculated the bandwidths?

Tags: discrete-signals, bandwidth, analog

In these days we can able to easily calculate the bandwidths with the help of technology, but in olden days where people used the analog phones, how did they calculated the bandwidths?

Comment: sliderules. (dummy chars to make it 30)

Comment: Perhaps you should read a short story [The Feeling of Power](http://www.themathlab.com/writings/short%20stories/feeling.htm) by Isaac Asimov and then edit your question appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have used a sweepable oscillator for input with an oscilloscope to examine the output response in one engineering course lab, then compared a graph of the lab experimental results with some slide rule calculations.